# Is there a PC-to-phone application?

Tags: software-recommendation, phone

Is there an application (non-commercial) to make phone calls from PC to phone on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 11):

## [Ekiga](http://packages.ubuntu.com/Ekiga)

It might work for you - it is the FOSS alternative to Skype.

Comment: Link us, please?

Comment: Ekiga is serious VOIP support

Comment: It is available in the software center. Home page is http://ekiga.org/

Comment: Is Ekiga's protocol available on Empathy?

Comment: And I don't see any feature that says anything about phone calls. Who exactly do you have to pay for phone calls?

Comment: @Oxwivi http://wiki.ekiga.org/index.php/Using_Ekiga_to_do_PC-to-phone_calls

Comment: @Oxwivi , you can use Ekiga's service in Empathy, but there is no guarantee of it working.

Answer (score 4):

You can get Skype from the Ubuntu Partner Repository you just need to turn it on 1st, see here for more details: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype

Comment: When skype is installed, you need to buy skype-out credit which allows you to call normal and mobile phones. This works great.

Answer (score 4):

## SIP Clients

These all are SIP clients which means they all can be used to call each other and they just need a SIP address (like your mobile number) . You can also register to a commercial VoIP provider(which supports SIP) to place calls to normal phone line or cell phone .

You can get a free SIP address from [here](https://www.ekiga.net/?page=register).

[Ekiga](http://www.ekiga.org/) (available in the software center)

> Ekiga (formely known as GnomeMeeting) is an open source SoftPhone, Video Conferencing and Instant Messenger application over the Internet.

PC to Phone calls in ekiga .

> [Default provider](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ekiga#Register%20to%20a%20commercial%20VoIP%20provider%20%28landline%20and%20mobile%20phones%29)
>
> The default provider is [Diamondcard
> Worldwide Communication Service](https://www.diamondcard.us/), which
> offers these [rates](https://www.diamondcard.us/exec/voip-rep-acc-type?priInc=/ekiga?sr=/secondary/e/ekiga&pr=/templates&ht=/templates&secInc=/ekiga?sr=/secondary/e/ekiga&pr=/templates&ht=/secondary/e/ekiga&secAbs=/home/diamond/secondary/e/ekiga&secRel=/secondary/e/ekiga&priAbs=/home/diamond/templates&priRel=/templates&secId=ekiga&lc=)
>
> - To purchase the account, go in Tools -> PC-To-Phone Account. You
>   absolutely need to purchase the
>   account from the PC-To-Phone
>   configuration window or it won't work.
> - Once you have opened an account, login to your account to look up your
>   Account Number and PIN. Don't confuse
>   these with your username and password!
>   Enter the account number and PIN in the appropriate fields in the
>   window and enable the PC-To-Phone
>   service.
> - If you need to edit the account under Edit->Accounts, you should use
>   account number and PIN here also, even
>   though it says "user" and "password".
> - You are now ready to do PC-To-Phone
>   calls at very low rates all over the
>   world.
> - To dial a number, simply add "00"
>   followed by the country code, and by
>   the phone number you want to reach.
>
> For example, sip:003210111111 to call
> number 10111111 in Belgium.

[SFLphone](http://sflphone.org/) (available in the software center)

> SFLphone is a robust standards-compliant enterprise softphone, for desktop and embedded systems. It is designed to handle several hundreds of calls a day. SFLphone is available under the GNU GPL license, version 3.

[Twinkle](http://www.twinklephone.com/)  (available in the software center)

> Twinkle is a softphone for your voice over IP and instant messaging communcations using the SIP protocol. You can use it for direct IP phone to IP phone communication or in a network using a SIP proxy to route your calls and messages.

[Yate VoIP](http://yate.null.ro/pmwiki/) (available in the software center)

> YATE is a telephony engine aimed at creating a telephony server that performs well enough to deal with PBX requirements and also flexible enough for complex Gateway and IVR solutions.
>
> YateClient uses the same telephony code to produce a software desktop VoIP (SIP, H.323, IAX2) phone. yate-qt4 uses this to provide such a telephony

[QuteCom](http://trac.qutecom.org/wiki/QuteCom)  (available in the software center)

> QuteCom is a community of enthusiasts and developers, creating free software products related to communication over IP. The flagship product of the QuteCom project is a softphone which allows you to make free PC to PC video and voice calls, and to integrate all your IM contacts in one place.

[Linphone](http://www.linphone.org/) (available in the software center)

> Linphone is an internet phone or Voice Over IP phone (VoIP).
> With linphone you can communicate freely with people over the internet,
> with voice, video, and text instant
> messaging.
> Linphone makes use of the SIP protocol , an open standard for
> internet telephony. You can use
> Linphone with any SIP VoIP operator,
> including our free SIP audio/video
> service

[Jitsi](http://jitsi.org/)

> Jitsi - Open Source Video Calls and Chat
> Secure video calls, conferencing, chat, desktop sharing, file transfer, support for your favorite OS, and IM network. All this, and more, in Jitsi - the most complete and advanced open source communicator.

[Blink](http://icanblink.com/index.phtml)

> A state of the art, easy to use SIP client
> Available for Mac, Windows and Linux

Comment: @Achu you need to register to a commercial VOIP provider .

Answer (score 4):

**use VIBER**

Download viber app in your android or iphone. Install it.

Go to http://www.viber.com/en/

Download .deb package from the site.

Install it.

An authentication PIN will go to your smartphone app. Enter that PIN in your desktop app. Intallation will be complete.

Now from google store or apple store add money to your viber wallet.

Start making calls from you PC.

Check the rates from their website.

Answer (score 2):

YATE (Yet Another Telephony Engine) is a full featured VOIP client which supports FWD, iptel,sipgate, Gtalk, ekiga and voxgratia.

Homepage: http://yate.null.ro/pmwiki/

Comment: Link info about the PC-to-phone aspect.

Comment: @Oxwivi SIP can do PC to Phone so there is no need to keep asking for links.

Comment: @Roland, I know it can, but whose service do we use for it?

Comment: @Oxwivi that's up to the user, since Yate supports more than one service, and most of them support that feature.

Comment: @Roland, that's the thing, I did not find those services, and I'm asking for a link that tells me what services supporting yate are available.

Comment: @Oxwivi - this is the client's page, contains most of the info you need http://yateclient.yate.ro/

Comment: @Roland, so it's only Google?

Comment: No, any SIP service that supports calling from PC to Phone (like Ekiga)

Comment: @Oxwivi - which client do yo wish it to support? the link Roland provided gives you a few choices, not just Google.

Comment: @Roland, @Mark, sorry for the pain I am. I don't know any SIP service provider...

Comment: @Oxwivi - I'm not sure of your location but the following is a good list of providers http://www.sipcenter.com/sip.nsf/html/Service+Providers

Answer (score 1):

[Skype](http://www.skype.com) works in Ubuntu, but it's not FOSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use G-mail as sagarchalise suggested, and you can make calls out of the U.S. for free if you download the Firefox add-on [AnonymoX](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/anonymox/) it helps with tricking your system into thinking it's in a different country.

Answer (score 0):

[Gmail](http://gmail.com) what else. :)
First install [Google voice and video plugin](http://www.google.com/chat/video) then follow [this.](http://www.google.com/chat/voice/)

Comment: That only seems to work on America, as far as I know.

Comment: USA and Canada can be called for free. Other countries list with rates are here https://www.google.com/voice/b/0/rates

Comment: You cannot use it outside of the US/Canada.

Answer (score 0):

The can install something called a "softphone" and then you can connect over "sip" to termination services (such as google voice) which act as the gateway form internet to phone networks so you can connect w/ real phones.